# .xslx file won't return cell value using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am very new to coding, and I'm starting with Python. I am trying to use openpyxl as part of a tutorial. Specifically, I am attempting to print a value of a specific cell within a sheet in an Excel workbook. I have followed along with the tutorial, added the file to my project, and have the same code as in the instructional video, but I am having a hard time understanding the error. At first Pycharm didn't recognize the directory, so I fixed that but it still returns several errors. Hoping that someone can enlighten a lost novice! I greatly appreciate it!!

**Here's the code:**

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook("transactions.xlsx")

sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

**#instead of the method below, I have also tried: cell = sheet["a1"] to specify the cell I want.**

cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)

print(cell.value)
```

**Here's the error:**

```
C:\Users\acost\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/acost/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/scratch_3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acost\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.1\scratches\scratch_3.py", line 2, in 
<module>
     wb = xl.load_workbook("transactions.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\acost\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\acost\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\acost\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transactions.xlsx'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You can specify the full path of `transactions.xlsx` e.g `/home/user/filename.ext` or place the `transactions.xlsx` file within the same directory as your python file, or I would say run path. Which is likely to be `C:\Users\acost\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.1\scratches`

Answer (score 1):

Zeromika's comment is correct, this is just an elaboration thereof:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

## OPTION 1: move excel file to your python project folder

# in order for this to work, the 'transactions.xlsx' file
# must be in the same folder as this python script
wb = load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

cell_value = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value

print(cell_value)


## OPTION 2: use full path to file
# NOTE: this is a raw string (r-string), it allows us to use special characters without escaping them
# if we didn't use a raw string here, we would have to escape the backslashes like this:
# file_path = "C:\\Users\\acost\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.1\\scratches\\transactions.xlsx"
file_path = r"C:\Users\acost\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.1\scratches\transactions.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

cell_value = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value

print(cell_value)
```